# Variable scope in Shopify Sections

Tags: shopify-template

I'm trying to use a variable in my section file but it doesn't appear to be inherited from it's parent template.

For example:

**index.liquid**

```
{% assign foo = "bar" %}
{% section 'example' %}
```

**sections/example.liquid**

```
<h1>{{ foo }}</h1>

{% schema %}
{
    "name": "Example",
    "settings": [
       ...
    ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

It will not output the value of `{{ foo }}`, instead I just get: `<h1></h1>` as if the variable was never defined.

I thought sections would work like snippets, where anything defined in the parent template would be in scope in the included snippet:

**index.liquid**

```
{% assign foo = "bar" %}
{% include 'example' %}
```

**snippets/example.liquid**

```
<h1>{{ foo }}</h1>
```

Where I would get `<h1>bar</h1>` when rendered.

- Is this a bug, or intended behaviour?
- Is there a way I can include a section and use variable from some form of outer-scope?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is intended behaviour, I managed to find a way round it and thought I would post my *not-perfect but workable* solution:

**sections/example.liquid**

```
<h1><!-- foo --></h1>
```

You can use capture, to get the contents of the section as a string and use string filters on the captured markup:

**index.liquid**

```
{% assign foo = "bar" %}
{% capture section %}{% section 'example' %}{% endcapture %}
{{ section | replace: '<!-- foo -->', foo }}
```

You could of course replace any string, with your variable. But I found HTML comments work well because if you forget to run the replace, or don't need to - nothing is rendered.

If you wanted to do something more complex, like remove some markup from the section you could:

**sections/example.liquid**

```
<div>

    <!-- REMOVE_TITLE? -->
    <h1>{{ section.settings.title }}</h1>
    <!-- REMOVE_TITLE? -->

    <ul>
        {% for block in section.blocks %}
            <li>{{ block.settings.image | img_url: '300x' | img_tag }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then you could do something like:

```
{% capture section %}{% section 'example' %}{% endcapture %}
{% assign parts = section | split: '<!-- REMOVE_TITLE? -->' %}
{% for part in parts %}
    {% assign mod = forloop.index | modulo: 2 %}
    {% if mod > 0 %}{{ part }}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is probably one of the dirtiest things i've seen work around Shopify & Liquid, bravo!

Comment: I thought I had seen everything... Absolutely one of the dirtiest tricks on Shopify! Thanks you so much!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do it with js?

Comment: You can also send it with the 'param WITH'

Comment: @FabricioG In this particular example, yes JS would result in somewhat cleaner code. But my actual implementation would have resulted in a lot of superfluous HTML that I didn't want to duplicate for SEO reasons. The "with" param didn't work for me while using section, only with include.

Comment: @chrishale You absolute devil - this is evil genius. Thanks.

Comment: @chrishale man this is so filthy but it's saving me right now.

Answer (score 2):

I would assign all your variables in a snippet and the keep including this same snippet in whichever scope you need to use the variables in....

That is a fairly DRY approach.

Also anything defined in config/settings_schema.json has a global scope but it can be given new values in theme settings by end users.